# Sum Previous Years rows in SAS, 3 groups

Tags: sql, sas

I would like to Sum, for each Codinv and Class, values of previous years listed in column D.

Thank you Rigerta. Here is my New Request. Now that I think about that, when there is just one row per CodInv per Class, it should show the same value as D. Hence, I would like a new column to be calculated as follows

```
 Codinv    Class      year        D       NewColumn   
----------------------------------------------------------
  13       C08F       1977        5         5
  76       C01B       1999        1         1
  76       C21D       2005        2         2
  76       C23C       1998        2         2
  76       C23C       1999        2         4
```

I would change the code as follows, but it still does not work

As I read online, I tried with

```
data Want;                                                           
set Have;                                                           
by Codinv Class year;                                                             
retain NewColumn;                                              
if first.Class then NewColumn=D; output; 
if last.year NewColumn=NewColumn+D;                             
run;
```

It worked well with another analysis I had to do where I sorted by Codinv and Year only, now that I am doing it with three I tried different variations, but it is showing missing data for all rows or 0... Can you help me out? Forever Grateful

Answer (score 1):

You're close with your attempt, I've modified it to produce the desired output.  A summary of the changes I've made are :

- Removed the `retain` statement.  The method I've used adopts an automatic retain, so isn't necessary.
- Initialise NewColumn to 0 each time the class changes
- Add D to NewColumn for each row. (x+y, as used here, creates an implied retain)
- Removed the `output` statement.  This is implied at the end of the data step, so isn't needed.
- Removed the `if last.year...` line as it is not necessary
- Strictly speaking, having year in the `by` statement isn't necessary, but it is useful to keep in to ensure the data is sorted properly.

  ```
  data have;
  input Codinv Class $ year D;
  datalines;
  13       C08F       1977        5
  76       C01B       1999        1
  76       C21D       2005        2
  76       C23C       1998        2
  76       C23C       1999        2
  ;
  run;

  data Want;                                                           
  set Have;                                                           
  by Codinv Class year;                                                             
  if first.Class then NewColumn=0;
  newcolumn+D;
  run;
  ```

Comment: Hi Longfish, thank you for your availability. When I run the code NewColumn shows the cumulative sum of Column D by without grouping at all. Any reason for that? I am wondering if it is a problem related to the way I named Class which is actually this: '4DigitCLMN'n formatted as character. Below you can find the real code I am running based on your suggestion data WouldLike; set have; by codinv '4DigitCLMN'n year; if first.'4DigitCLMN'n then NewColumn=0; NewColumn+D; run;

Comment: Check the VALUES of your BY variables. If the variable '4DIGITCLMN'd only has one observations per unique value within each value of CODINV then there is nothing to accumulate. Perhaps your need to change order of the variables in the BY statement? Also make sure that NewColumn is NOT already on your input dataset. Because then it will be reset to the value from the dataset every time the SET statement executes defeating the attempt to retain the sum across observations.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your interest! I confirm that there are multiple 4digits codes within each codinv. From the table posted for instance there are two C23C for codinv 76, which should have count 4 in NewColumn for year 1999 as result of the grouping. New Column is not already in the input dataset. Thanks again, let me know if you think there are alternative ways or reasons for which the code is not working

Comment: I have just renamed the column deleting the initial number and It worked now. SAS EG renamed like that the column so I was not giving it too much importance. Thank you very much again for your interest